# replace full bbcode tag by empty not working php

Tags: php

I need to replace a full bbcode tag by an empty space (in this example by a "M")

This is my php code so far

```
$string ="
 hello
 [MSG='user1, comment: 253434, userid: 1232'] TEXT1[/MSG]

   [MSG='user2, comment: 343425, userid: 4231'] 
   TEXT2
   [/MSG]

   [MSG='user3, comment: 234345, userid: 1423']
   TEXT3
  [/MSG]
   [MSG='user4, comment: 253434, userid: 123242']
   TEXT4
  text 4
  text 4
  [/MSG]

  [MSG='user5, comment: 251234, userid: 1652'] TEXT5[/MSG]
 hello
 ";
```

regex replacement

```
 $string = preg_replace("[MSG=\'(.*?)\'](.*?)[\/MSG]", "M", $string);
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**

```
 hello M M M M M hello
```

Im using this regex `[MSG=\'(.*?)\'](.*?)[\/MSG]` what is wrong with it?

Comment: You are missing a delimiter in your regex, and you might need the modifier `s`.

Comment: you mean something like this? `/[MSG=(.*?)[\/MSG]/s` it doesnt work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this [regex](https://regex101.com/r/UThxAe/1)

or

```
$re = '/(\[MSG=.*?\[\/MSG\]\s+)/ms';
$str = '$string ="
 hello
 [MSG=\'user1, comment: 253434, userid: 1232\'] TEXT1[/MSG]

   [MSG=\'user2, comment: 343425, userid: 4231\'] 
   TEXT2
   [/MSG]

   [MSG=\'user3, comment: 234345, userid: 1423\']
   TEXT3
  [/MSG]
   [MSG=\'user4, comment: 253434, userid: 123242\']
   TEXT4
  text 4
  text 4
  [/MSG]

  [MSG=\'user5, comment: 251234, userid: 1652\'] TEXT5[/MSG]
 hello';
$subst = ' M';

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);

echo "The result of the substitution is ".$result;
```

```
 hello M M M M Mhello
```

Comment: thank you. but the bbcode has no backslashes inside.

Comment: that would make no difference. Answer is still valid. Check the actual link I sent, there are no backslashes in the actual example... the `code generator` there escapes those, you do not need to use it. Try it on your end.